# Como hacer que un boton en react no se ralice onclick al hacer refresh

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs

**Problema**: Tengo un botón que su función es hacer un logout, pero cuando inicio sesión como la página realiza un autorefresh de esta, automáticamente se pulsa y realiza el logout, es decir no permite loguearse a la gente porque las desloguea automáticamente en cuanto carga la otra página con el botón de logout.

## Código

```
return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div className="justify-content-center row">
          <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Bienvenido</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="justify-content-center row">
            <button
              type='button'
              className="btn btn-warning"
              onClick={setUserInfo(null)}
            >
              Logout
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="App container">
      <div className="justify-content-center row">
        <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Inicio de sesion</h1>
      </div>
      <Link to="/Register" className="nav-item nav-link active">
        Registro
      </Link>
      <div className="justify-content-center row">
        <form className="mt-5" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <label>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input required type="text" onChange={(e) => setUsuario(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <label>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input
              required
              type="password"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <div>
            <button type='button' className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
              Iniciar Sesión
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta cambiar esto en la línea 10 del código que publicaste

```
onClick={()=>{setUserInfo(null)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que está pasando es que cuando accionas un form se envia en automatico el formulario. Lo que necesitas es evitar que encuando presiones el boton se corra en automatico.

Deberías modificar el evento del form para realizar la acción que quieras hacer:

```
const handleLogin= event => {  
  event.preventDefault();
  (... Aquí agrega otras funciones que queiras)
};
```

Después de esto lo deberas asignar en el form `<form onSubmit={handleLogin}>`